# AutoComplete-ready ComboBox in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, combobox, autocomplete, silverlight-3.0

Has anybody out there had a situation where you needed to implement an "editable" ComboBox in Silverlight?  My client wants a ComboBox in their UI that allows the user to place focus on the selection box and start typing to automatically pull up the desired value from the available items, rather than requiring use of the drop-down list.

This feature is available, I know, in several implementations from third parties.  For example, you can make this happen fairly easily with Telerik's RadControls for Silverlight.  However, my client is restricted to using the Silverlight 3 Toolkit, with no third-party tools or plug-ins.

Any suggestions for a quick, down-and-dirty implementation?  Any guidance or links are appreciated!

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Why aren't you using the auto-complete combo box from the toolkit?

Comment: Did not think was available?  There is an AutoCompleteBox in the toolkit, but is that not a TextBox?  Guess I haven't played around with it enough, but my understanding was the ComboBox could not be made editable?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we had the same problem.

We went ahead and used the AutoCompleteBox from the Silverlight 3 tookit.  Their implementation has a lot of things missing that we wanted.  Because of these limitations, we created our own that inherited from it.  It worked great and was very simple to do.  Any tutorial for making your own control that inherits from another will help you.

Have fun.  Since the toolkit is open source, you can always look at the code for guidance.

You can see the samples from the toolkit here: https://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html